# How to identify the frequencies of periodic peak signals in a noisy time series? (with R)

Tags: r, time-series, signal-processing, frequency, signal-detection

Suppose to have two time series with peak signals at different frequencies, like these two:

```
signal1 <- tsibble(timestamp = t,
                   value = ifelse(seq(1,length(t)) %% 5 == 0, 15, 0))
signal1
```

> ```
> # A tsibble: 96 x 2 [1M]
>    timestamp value
>        <mth> <dbl>
>  1  2011 Jan     0
>  2  2011 Feb     0
>  3  2011 Mar     0
>  4  2011 Apr     0
>  5  2011 May    15
>  6  2011 Jun     0
>  7  2011 Jul     0
>  8  2011 Aug     0
>  9  2011 Sep     0
> 10  2011 Oct    15
> # ... with 86 more rows
> ```

```
signal1 %>% autoplot()
```

[image: signal1 plot]

```
signal2 <- tsibble(timestamp = t,
                   value = ifelse(seq(1,length(t)) %% 9 == 0, 13, 0))

signal2
```

> ```
> # A tsibble: 96 x 2 [1M]
>    timestamp value
>        <mth> <dbl>
>  1  2011 Jan     0
>  2  2011 Feb     0
>  3  2011 Mar     0
>  4  2011 Apr     0
>  5  2011 May     0
>  6  2011 Jun     0
>  7  2011 Jul     0
>  8  2011 Aug     0
>  9  2011 Sep    13
> 10  2011 Oct     0
> # ... with 86 more rows
> ```

```
signal2 %>% autoplot()
```

[image: signal2 plot]

Joining the two signals we obtain this composite signal:

```
tsibble(timestamp = t,
        value = signal1$value + signal2$value) %>% autoplot()
```

[image: composite signal]

Now we disturb this composite signal with white noise:

```
noise <- tsibble(timestamp = t,
                  value = rnorm(length(t), mean=0, sd=10))

final_ts <- tsibble(timestamp = t,
                value = noise$value + signal1$value + signal2$value) 

final_ts %>% autoplot()
```

[image: final_ts plot]

Starting from this noisy time series, I would like to identify the different frequencies of the periodic peak signals buried in the noise, in this case  5/12 and 9/12 (assuming 12 months as the unit of time).

How to do that? Is the Fourier analysis the best way to do that?

Comment: I would suggest that you do a spectral (Fourier) analysis. I have always used it for periodicity and frequencies.